# Date difference between end date to start date

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data alooks like below.

```
id   from data   to date
1   2015-03-09   2015-03-14
2   2015-02-22   2015-02-24
2   2015-05-06   2015-05-17
3   2015-02-12   2015-02-16
4   2015-03-10   2015-03-16
4   2015-03-22  2015-04-07
4   2015-06-07  2015-07-07
4   2015-07-06   2015-07-07
4   2015-08-02   2015-08-07
```

I want to create a seperate variable which is the difference between the to date and the next from date grouped by id.
So the first time of the id will be NA.I tried the below method based on the other answer in stackoverflow and I could not
achieve that.

```
library(data.table)
chf1 = data.table(id = chf$id,from date = chf$f.date,to_date = chf$t.date)
setkey(chf1,id)
chf1[,diff:=c(NA,difftime(from_date, to_date, units = "days")),by=id]
```

The output look like

```
id   from_date   to_date      difference
1   2015-03-09   2015-03-14     NA
2   2015-02-22   2015-02-24     NA
2   2015-05-06   2015-05-17     71
3   2015-02-12   2015-02-16     NA
4   2015-03-10   2015-03-16     NA
4   2015-03-22  2015-04-07      6
4   2015-06-07  2015-06-10      64
4   2015-07-06   2015-07-07     26
4   2015-08-02   2015-08-07     26
```

Comment: I think you need `chf1[,diff:=difftime(from_date, to_date, units = "days"),by=id]`  The `chf1$from_date` gets the whole column and grouping by 'id' will not have any effect.  Also, `diff` needs the output to have NA or 0 or anyother value appended, no the `difftime`

Comment: I understand the mistake. But after changing the chf1$from_date to from_date I cannot achieve the expected output.

Comment: Because you already changed the values.  Please run from the `data.table` creation step

Comment: Why does your input and expected output have different values in `to_date` column in one record?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three issues in the code

1) `chf1$from_date`, `chf1$to_date` gets the whole column, so there is no effect of grouping by 'id'

2) `difftime` gives output with the same length as the initial column length.

3) As `difftime` takes the difference between each element of 'from_date' with corresponding element of 'to_date', there is no need for `by = id`

Therefore, the code can be

```
chf1[, diff1:=difftime(from_date, to_date, units = "days")]
chf1
#   id  from_date    to_date    diff1
#1:  1 2015-03-09 2015-03-14  -5 days
##2:  2 2015-02-22 2015-02-24  -2 days
#3:  2 2015-05-06 2015-05-17 -11 days
#4:  3 2015-02-12 2015-02-16  -4 days
#5:  4 2015-03-10 2015-03-16  -6 days
#6:  4 2015-03-22 2015-04-07 -16 days
#7:  4 2015-06-07 2015-07-07 -30 days
#8:  4 2015-07-06 2015-07-07  -1 days
#9:  4 2015-08-02 2015-08-07  -5 days
```

---

Based on the description in OP's code, if we need to get the difference between the next value of 'from_date', after grouping by 'id', use the `difftime` on the `shift`ed 'from_date' with that of 'to_date' and assign (`:=` it to 'diff1'.

```
chf1[,  diff1 := difftime(shift(from_date, type = "lead"), to_date, 
                        units = "days") , by = id]
chf1
#  id  from_date    to_date   diff1
#1:  1 2015-03-09 2015-03-14 NA days
#2:  2 2015-02-22 2015-02-24 71 days
#3:  2 2015-05-06 2015-05-17 NA days
#4:  3 2015-02-12 2015-02-16 NA days
#5:  4 2015-03-10 2015-03-16  6 days
#6:  4 2015-03-22 2015-04-07 61 days
#7:  4 2015-06-07 2015-07-07 -1 days
#8:  4 2015-07-06 2015-07-07 26 days
#9:  4 2015-08-02 2015-08-07 NA days
```

Or it could be

```
chf1[, diff1 := difftime(from_date, shift(to_date), units = "days"), by = id]
```

#### data

```
chf <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
f.date = structure(c(16503, 
16488, 16561, 16478, 16504, 16516, 16593, 16622, 16649), class = "Date"), 
t.date = structure(c(16508, 16490, 16572, 16482, 16510, 16532, 
16623, 16623, 16654), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", 
 "f.date", "t.date"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

 chf1 = data.table(id = chf$id,from_date = chf$f.date,to_date = chf$t.date)
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the code in the question and it was my error. But still I did not get my expected output even after executing all the steps again

Comment: @ssan I updated with the data and expected output.  Please run using this data

Comment: @ssan What is your expected output?  Your `difftime` code is getting the difference between each value of `from_date` with corresponding value of `to_date` and for that `by = id'` is not needed.

Comment: thanks for the update. But if you see the diff1 in output for the 2nd record it should be NA and third record will be 71. similarly the difference between 6th to_date and 7th from_date can't be -1. This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @ssan If the 3rd one is 71, how about `chf1[, diff1 := difftime(from_date, shift(to_date), units = "days"), by = id]`

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for your response. I think we can update this to the answer as well. Can I edit the answer?

Comment: :@akrun is there a way that the difference between the to_date and from_date can be reflected in the first record rather than the second record. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @ssan What do you meant by the first record.  Perhaps you need `chf1[, diff1 := difftime(from_date, shift(to_date, type = "lead"), units = "days"), by = id]`

Comment: To gain speed in @akrun's elegant solution we could use the `IDate` class of `data.table`. So it'd be: `cols <- c('from_date ','to_date'); chf1[,(cols):=lapply(.SD,as.IDate),.SDcols=cols]; chf1[, diff2 := from_date-shift(to_date), by = id]`